# Python dictionary list retrieval process

Tags: python, dictionary, arraylist, list-comprehension

I have been working to solve an issue involving a zip code to a territory based on a start range and end range within each territory.  I can't seem to figure out how to use the dictionary below to run through my list of zip codes. Ultimately I need a list that says zip code 6015 belongs to territory A

```
mydict = {'Territory a': [60000,60999], 'Territory b': [90000,90999], 'Territory c': [70000,700999]}
myzips = [60015,60016,60017,90001,90002,90003,76550,76556,76557]
```

I've have research how to call values in a dictionary, but I don't see there is a good way to call the key, which in my case is the territory description. I'm not totally convinced that a dictionary is the way to go, but I can't think of another way all the elements stay together to be called on in a future function or loop.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries are not meant to be used that way. Nonetheless, here is a solution that solves your issue.

```
mydict={'Territory a':[60000,60999],'Territory b': [90000,90999],'Territory c': [70000,70099]}
myzips =[60015,60016,60017,90001,90002,90003,76550,76556,76557]

for zipCode in myzips:
    for territory, postCodes in mydict.items():
        if (postCodes[0] <= zipCode <= postCodes[1]):
            print(str(zipCode) + " is in " + territory)
            break
```

For each zip given, we check if it is within the postal code range for all territories. If it is, we print it.

Comment: Or, you could do `postCodes[0] <= zip <= postCodes[1]`, which should be a bit faster. Also, you might want to use a different variable name than `zip` because it is a built-in function.

Comment: Updated the post! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I would change `mydict` so the key is a zipcode and the value is the territory. Presumably there are no zip codes that belong to two territories.

```
newdict = {}
for territory, zipcodes in mydict.items():
    for zipcode in zipcodes:
        newdict[zipcode] = territory
```

Now you can get the territory for all the zipcodes in your list

```
for zipcode in myzips:
    print(zipcode, newdict.get(zipcode)
```

Note that in the data you posted, none of the zip codes in `myzips` are in `mydict`, so `newdict.get` will return `None`.

Comment: You need to consider the range of the zipcodes. While he lists Territory a as 60000, 60999, he wants all values in between them as well. Reversing the key:val will not work in this scenario I think as it will only check against the boundary values.

Comment: Thank you Eric and Sri for your help.  This has helped out with my code a lot.  Concerning the "Presumably there are no zip codes that belong to two territories", in fact there are many overlaps that occur.  when I  put the code in, it takes the first match then moves on without considering other matches.  I think I need a while loop, but not sure.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work with the help of Sri and Eric. 
I got it to work.  I just made a distinct list for Territory(final_list) then loop through each one.

```
h = 0
while h < len(final_list) :

        for zipCode in myzips:
            for territory, postCodes in dict.items():
                if (postCodes[0] <= zipCode <= postCodes[1])and postCodes[2] == final_list[h] :
                    mylist2.append(str(zipCode)+","+territory)
                #break
        h += 1
```